# to install babel in windows

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs

I want to install babel(windows). but I got error.How can I fix this?

```sh
Staff ~/Desktop/react
$ npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-loader babel-present-react
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-core failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com proxy.company.com:8080
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Staff\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-05T09_55_48_364Z-debug.log
```

Comment: From a cursory glance, it looks like your machine is having trouble connecting to the npm registry (where all packages are stored). This can be seen in line 5 of your provided output. Can you navigate directly to the address (`https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-core`) in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Babel is a toolchain that is mainly used to convert ECMAScript 2015+ code into a backwards compatible version of JavaScript in current and older browsers or environments.

so first you need to install node js then  install npm package manager.

then install babel with this: npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli

or if you want to install react you can use "npm Create-React-App" is an officially supported way to create single-page React applications. by facebook